# Possible concurrency issue with ForEach and array of @State in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, concurrency

Edit 2: I added a screen recording below so the issue is even clearer. I am not satisfied with the current answers because I don't understand why bindings (async) update differently when dealing with arrays, and much more reliably when dealing with single structs (even if they are of the same type)

[image: Demo of suspected concurrency issue]

--

Edit: I updated the code (removed the ForEach and added a couple of print()) to make the lack of thread safety array issue even more obvious.

--

I'm writing a basic countdown timer on iOS using `try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))` before updating a @State variable. When the variable `MyStruct`, it seems to update fine, but if I place a few `MyStruct`-s in an Array then I get strange timings for updates that break the functionality of a basic timer counting down.

Here is my isolated example - you might have to **refresh the app a few times** or swap out my onAppear with a Button to see how inconsistent this behavior is.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var first = MyStruct(setTime: 15)
    @State var second = MyStruct(setTime: 10)
    @State var third = MyStruct(setTime: 5)
    
    @State var array = [MyStruct(setTime: 15), MyStruct(setTime: 10), MyStruct(setTime: 5)]
    
    @State var hasNotAppearedYet = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Seconds: \(Int(array[0].currentTime))").padding().font(.title3)
            Text("Seconds: \(Int(array[1].currentTime))").padding().font(.title3)
            Text("Seconds: \(Int(array[2].currentTime))").padding().font(.title3)
            
            Divider()
            
            Text("Seconds: \(first.currentTime)").padding().font(.title3)
            Text("Seconds: \(second.currentTime)").padding().font(.title3)
            Text("Seconds: \(third.currentTime)").padding().font(.title3)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(){
            if(hasNotAppearedYet){
                $array[0].startTimer(name: "arrayElement0")
                $array[1].startTimer(name: "arrayElement1")
                $array[2].startTimer(name: "arrayElement2")
                
                $first.startTimer(name: "FIRST")
                $second.startTimer(name: "SECOND")
                $third.startTimer(name: "THIRD")
                
                hasNotAppearedYet = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
    var setTime: Double
    var currentTime: Double = 0
}

extension Binding<MyStruct> {
    func startTimer(name: String){
        Task {
            wrappedValue.currentTime = wrappedValue.setTime
            print(name, wrappedValue.currentTime)
            
            while (wrappedValue.currentTime > 0) {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                try Task.checkCancellation()
                wrappedValue.currentTime -= 1
                print(name, wrappedValue.currentTime)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Same weird results on Simulator and real iPhone

Comment: That floating Task in start timer is an issue. Use .task(id:) not onAppear

Comment: Also, timer firing is not very accurate.  A better approach is to compute the end `Date` and then run the timer at about 0.2 seconds to update your display using `timeIntervalSinceNow` on your end date.https://github.com/paulw11/stopwatch

Comment: @loremipsum But why do the individual variables update so accurately, but the structs in the array do not?

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried changing to Double and updating every 200 milliseconds with very similar results. The issue is still there for array elements

Comment: Don't use doubles or ints. Use `Date`

Comment: Need to use .task in SwiftUI not Task{} otherwise it definitely will be inconsistent as you found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are lots of issues in this code, the fundamental problem is that you have multiple threads updating individual value type instances in the same array at the same time.

Specifically, `startTimer` is a non-isolated `async` function which (by virtue of [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md)) does not run on the main thread. So you have multiple threads updating the individual values within the same array, without the sufficient synchronization. It is hard to be specific re the manifested behavior (as it is dependent upon a lot of Foundation implementation details), but it is not remotely surprising that it is problematic to mutate multiple values within the same array from separate threads at the same time.

FWIW, isolating `startTimer` to a global actor addresses the immediate problem. In this trivial example, I would isolate it to the main actor as you updating a property used by the `View`.

But this is not the whole answer: At a bare minimum, I would advise changing the “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting to “Complete” and review/resolve all of the warnings it raises.

Comment: FWIW, other unrelated observations with this code: 1. We should avoid unstructured concurrency and use `.task` view modifier. 2. I would advise against this `Binding` extension approach (it feels like you’re trying to achieve reference-like semantics with value types; if you want reference semantics, then use reference types). 3. We often reach for Observation framework or `ObservableObject` pattern for this sort of stuff. Etc.

Comment: The binding extension was just an attempt at syntactic sugar from a newbie to Swift. 

I’m satisfied with your answer @Rob cuz you highlight the key difference between the two approaches: in one case I have 3 separate structs being updated by 3 separate threads. That is by definition thread safe. However, 1 array containing 3 structs inside is still 1 larger value type containing 3 other value types inside. Thus I ended up with 1 value type being edited by 3 threads which, unsurprisingly, causes concurrency issues. Therefore, forcing sync by any means, including using a global actor works

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are seeing is the natural behavior of `async await` the "actor" decides what to do and when to do it.

In this case the actor is juggling the timers and the UI updates.

Here are some things you can do to stabilize the `while`

1. Get rid of the `Binding` `extension` because `Binding` is not `Sendable` and therefore not safe to use inside `async/await`. You can turn on strict concurrency to see the warning. `Binding` by itself can introduce data races.
2. Use `.task` instead of `Task` so you can hold on to and stabilize the "timer".
3. Set the priority for the `task` it won't be a perfect second but it should be much better. The `await` is a second but there are other lines of code so the true time is likely 1+ seconds.

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct TimerTestView: View {
        @State var first = MyStruct(setTime: 15)
        @State var second = MyStruct(setTime: 10)
        @State var third = MyStruct(setTime: 5)
        
        @State var array = [MyStruct(setTime: 15), MyStruct(setTime: 10), MyStruct(setTime: 5)]
        
        @State var hasNotAppearedYet = true
        @State private var date: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 16, to: .init())!
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack { 
                Text(date, style: .timer) //Added an Apple timer to compare
                HStack { //Changed UI so I can see things side by side 
                    MyStructView(item: $array[0])
                    MyStructView(item: $first)
                }
                HStack {
                    MyStructView(item: $array[1])
                    MyStructView(item: $second)
                }
                HStack {
                    MyStructView(item: $array[2])
                    MyStructView(item: $third)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
        }
    }

    struct MyStruct: Identifiable, Sendable {
        let id: UUID = .init()
        var setTime: Double
        var currentTime: Double = 0
    }


    #Preview {
        TimerTestView()
    }

    @MainActor
    struct MyStructView: View {
        @Binding var item: MyStruct
        var body: some View {
            Text("Seconds:\n \(item.currentTime)").padding().font(.title3)
            // Use the id to stabilize the task
                .task(id: item.id, priority: .userInitiated) { //Set the priority & hold on to the Task
                    do {
                        try await startTimer(name: item.id.uuidString)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
        }
        func startTimer(name: String) async throws { 
            let start = Date()
            item.currentTime = item.setTime
            print(name, item.currentTime)
            
            while (item.currentTime > 0) {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                try Task.checkCancellation()
                item.currentTime -= 1
                print(name, item.currentTime)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at the gif I added to the original post. I am very puzzled about why on some refreshes the Text views with array[index] get 0 instead of getting reset to the correct values. The clocks being a bit off is one of the more subtle forms of this problem. If you refresh a few times, you will see egregius results.

Comment: @vullnetyy you shouldn't get that with this setup, i ran it several times and other than lasting more than a second all the timers update. Binding isnt Sendable it isnt safe

Comment: I have found other ways to deal with this issue. But it bothers me that I don't have a clear answer about what is going on under the hood. I don't know what part of your suggestion makes it better... is it that you added the MainActor macro? Is it that you used .task()? More details would be appreciated and potentially get your answer accepted.

Btw, I have tried adding priority and it didn't help at all.

Comment: @vullnetyy NP its a whole picture thing just changing the priority wouldn't work because you aren’t forcing them onto the same actor. The idea is to limit async/await’s decisions by saying I want the work done here (main actor) with the highest priority (user initiated) and this (the id) tells them apart. The id also prevents the cancellation of the task when the view redraws but will cancel it if the view is destroyed. The floating Task you have in your code is known to cause issues with SwiftUI because of the value type nature (makes copies when redrawing) and Binding isn’t safe.