# Timer inside Task block never fires

Tags: swift

I have a problem with an asyncSequence that I want to restart after a certain amount of time if it throws an error:

```swift
func load() {
    myTask?.cancel()
    myTask = Task {
        do {
            for try await value in service.loadSomething() {
                print("received \(value)")
                // do something
            }
        } catch {
            // store timer in order to be able to cancel it when leaving the page
            retryTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: false) {[weak self] _ in
                self?.load()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(NB: I need a reference to the retry timer in order to be able to cancel the retry timer if the user leaves the page)

The problem is, the timer never fires. I isolated the problem in Playground and found that whenever I try to start a timer inside a task, it never fires. But if I wrap the timer initialisation inside a `Task { @MainActor`, then the timer fires as expected:

```swift
func loadSomething() {
    print("loadSomething called")
    Task {
        // Task { @MainActor in // <-- Comment this in, and the timer is fired. Without this, it is not fired
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { _ in
                loadSomething()
            }
        // }
    }
}

loadSomething()
```

Can somebody explain to me, why the timer must be initialised on the main thread and cannot be initialised inside a normal Task, please?

Comment: I haven't tested, and I'm not sure about the issue, but it wouldn't surprise me that it's missing a RunLoop, cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755587/swift-timer-scheduledtimer-doesnt-work

Comment: Why use a timer when you can `try await Task.sleep(...)`?

Comment: @Sweeper: Timer is used because I want to be able to cancel it when leaving the page later - as described in the comment in the catch block

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78202506/possible-concurrency-issue-with-foreach-and-array-of-state-in-swiftui/78203576?noredirect=1#comment137879486_78203576

Answer (score 3):

You could rewrite the function without using a timer

```
func load() {
    myTask = Task {
        while true {
            do {
                for try await value in loadSomething() {
                    print("received \(value)")
                    // do something
                }
            } catch is CancellationError {
                break //This will break out of the loop and exit the function
            } catch {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(60))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To cancel the infinite loop and the function call `cancel()` on the task

```
myTask.cancel()
```

Comment: Thanks, bug I need to be able to cancel the timer if the user leaves the page. I don't what it to continue updating then. I wrote that in a comment in the code, but since this is the second time this suggestion comes up, I will edit my question and specify this as a condition on the question :-)

Comment: @JRV this code does that too. It catches `CancellationError` and stops the loop. Just `cancel` the task when you want it to stop.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper.  JRV, I added an explanation to the answer

Comment: I tried this - it does not seem to work. When calling myTask.cancel, no CancellationError is thrown (or caught)

Comment: Ahh, adding try `Task.checkCancellation()` just after the `do`-line fixes it :-)

Comment: A similar solution works fine for me. Maybe the issue is with the function `loadSomething`, does it handle cancellations?